# How do I get an attribute from a DOM Node (not Element) in a type-safe way?

Tags: javascript, dom, flowtype

I'm writing a function that scrapes a DOM, and I'm using `Flow` for type safety.

Let's say I have some arbitrary collection of `DOM Node` of selector `.foo > span`, each with a data-attribute, `data-foo`.

If I want `data-foo` from each of them, this is how I'd normally do it:

```
// grab NodeList & convert to array
const fooNodeArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.foo > span'))

fooNodeArray.map(node => {
  return node.getAttribute('data-foo')
})
```

But according to Flow, this is not typesafe, as [the `Node` type](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.38.0/lib/dom.js#L377) doesn't always have a method `getAttribute()`

It turns out that `getAttribute()` (or the related `attributes` member) only exists on a `Node` when the `Node` is an `Element Node` (i.e., `Node.nodeType === 1`).

If these `Elements` had `id` or specific `className`, I could use `getElementById()/-className()`, but unfortunately they're only selectable with `.foo > span`.

So I tried something like this:

```
fooNodeArray.map(node => {
  return node.nodeType === 1 ? node.getAttribute('data-foo') : null
})
```

...but Flow continues to reject it.

I'm fairly certain this `nodeType` guard will protect against `TypeErrors`, but I'm trying to avoid ignoring Flow (or using `//$FlowFixMe` to suppress the error).

Is there a type-safe way to get an `attribute` from a `DOM Node` with the `DOM API`?

Comment: Try wrapping it in a `typeof node.getAttribute === "function"` check? I'm unfamiliar with how Flow parses your code, but that should be enough to avoid the *actual* type error.

Comment: What version of Flow are you using? Your snippet typechecks fine on the Flow site: https://flowtype.org/try/#0PTAEHMCcEMCNQHIHsAmBTAMgSwM4BdQAyUAYyQDsA3NSAvJUaSGATwCgzz9QAzJJZOgCCzaC1ABeUCNYA6HpCQBbABQokJAK5K05PLICOmmiwDKaADZoS9SEIsWVAcnn9QAPlA4ADtHJOASgC2DgpuaDw8SBwALmlRFgAeAH58SCxycE8pPgFUNBkxWSVobxVyfMlPAG82UFBINDxNSHJQCvRZcCahSPTYTTw0ZxQI6ABaXMC2AF8AgG4gA

Comment: thanks for pointing that out @loganfsmyth. I'm on v.37.  i did some checking and I believe the culprit was some manual typings I did to functions in my actual code that made Flow believe the `nodes` were `Nodes`, when they were actually `HTMLElement`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Node`s in DOM level 4 no longer have attributes (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Attr); attributes instead live exclusively on `Element` so you may need to indicate to Flow that inside your `node => { ... }` arrow function the `node` argument is of type `Element`, not generic type `Node`.

Note that this is technically already the case as `document.querySelectorAll` does *not* return a generic NodeList, but specifically a NodeList containing `Element` objects (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). So, that's another option: if you can tell Flow that your `fooNodeArray` is an `Element[]`, not a `Node[]`, it should not complain about `getAttribute` anymore.

Comment: hm yeah, now looking back through the [DOM Flow Types](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.38.0/lib/dom.js#L905), it looks like `querySelectorAll` returns `NodeList<HTMLElement>`. But since `HTMLElement` implements `Element`, it should recognize that a member of the the `querySelectorAll  NodeList` is an `Element` no?

Comment: One would certainly imagine. This might be a case where asking on the [Flow issue tracker](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues) is going to yield a better answer than Stackoverflow.